# Why is Resharper showing a red 'Cannot Resolve Symbol' error?

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2013, web-config, resharper

I have Resharper 10 installed in Visual Studio 2013.  My solution contains a view .cshtml file that displays a date using Razor.  However, Resharper displays the DateTime with a red warning highlight, and prompts me to import the System.DateTime namespace - please see the linked image:

[image]

The strange thing is that when my colleagues open the solution on their machines - exactly the same code, using the same version of VS2013 with the same Resharper version - there is no Resharper error.

The namespaces section of the Web.config file in the Views folder looks like this:

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
</namespaces>
```

If I add the System namespace, ie:

```
<add namespace="System" />
```

.. then the issue goes away.  But - this doesn't explain why the issue only appears on one machine, and not on others.

I've tried cleaning the solution, suspending & resuming Resharper, clearing the Resharper cache, deleting the .suo file for the project, etc.

This seems so simple, but I really cannot figure out why R# would warn me on one machine, but not on others, when the code and environment seem to be identical.

The solution builds and runs successfully, without any warnings.  If I disable Resharper, the error disappears.

Any suggestions? Could Resharper's warning be a result of some wider configuration issue on my machine?

Comment: Is project running ok on that machine?

Comment: So unless I'm wrong, your machine is right - that import is needed to reference DateTime. Perhaps your colleagues have just disabled r# for razor files, or just supressed that particular error?

Comment: .. possibly - but, when I disable Resharper, Visual Studio's intellisense indicates that it's perfectly happy with the @DateTime class name - ie, there's no error indicated from VS itself.  I've compared the Resharper settings on my machine with my collegues' machines - they're all the same.

Comment: When you click `Import 'System.DateTime'`... does it turn blue and look good and not complain anymore?

Comment: @maxshuty correct - importing System.DateTime makes the warning go away.  However, with Resharper disabled, there is no warning - ie, Visual Studio is perfectly happy without importing System.DateTime.  That's the thing that's confusing me.  That, and that the issue doesn't occur on other developers' machines.

Comment: @PastaMike if you really want to get it to go away then one thing you can have one of your coworkers who it's working for export their ReSharper settings and you can import all of their settings. It *should* go away then

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues *after* cleaning up my PC. So in my case I uninstalled an old visual studio and some dependencies (which were clearly marked as VS 2010), but that also ended up removing stuff in my older .net libraries. So ReSharper complained - and it could always be fixed by specifically referencing specific libraries.

My recommendation

1. Check what versions of .net your VS project is expecting
2. check that you have this version in your GAC (or if not, compare to the setup of your colleagues)
3. if you don't have the version, either upgrade the project to a newer .net, or re-install the older .net libraries, OR change your config-file to map the versions, allowing the new version to step in for the old ones.